# Buster setup : command not found

Tags: github, ghost-blog

I was looking to host my ghost blog into Github, i followed a youtube video, I have pip and node installed, buster also however when i try to run this command "buster setup" it's not found, any suggestion please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

install buster using python's pip package manager `$ pip install buster`